# Internet fails to connect on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 22.04, dns

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.

On waking up the laptop from sleep, the Wi-Fi gets connected but fails to connect to the internet; switching off Wi-Fi and then switching on doesn't work; doesn't `ping google.com` or `8.8.8.8`. This problem persists when I use other Wi-Fi connections.

I tried to bring the Wi-Fi interface down and then up using `ifconfig` command, it doesn't help. However, when I restart my laptop, the problem gets solved. But when I get the laptop into sleep again, the issue comes up again. It's tiresome to restart every time when I have applications running. And often I get "Your connection was interrupted. A network change was detected" error in the browser. I didn't get this error on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have my NetworkManager as my netplan renderer. So this is how my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` looks like:

> ```
> # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: NetworkManager
> ```

When I restart NetworkManager by the command `systemctl restart NetworkManager`, the problem gets solved. I can restart NetworkManager everytime I get this problem. But is there any other way I can solve this issue and what maybe the reason the internet cuts off?

Comment: check this out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1676810

Comment: `sudo dmesg` and check the errors, I found some firmware drivers are not loaded. If so, it's very simple.